# How to put value on top of column in bar chart kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'm doing with kibana version 8.5.2 and I want to put value text on the top of column like image (this is older version). But I cannot find anywhere to config, please help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the Aggregation based visualization option instead of Lens:

[image]

And then enable the option:

[image]